# Conditionally replace string in file PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, conditional-statements

I'm trying to replace a hostname with an FQDN located anywhere in a specific file. The following works fine, unless the FQDN is already in the file. If FQDN is there, it adds a second domain name to the FQDN.

```
$test = Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt
$test -replace ($compname, $fqdn)
```

Essentially, I need to replace if, and only if, the string matches compname, but doesn't match FQDN.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the parentheses around `$compname, $fqdn`

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue!

```
"(computer)(?!\.contoso\.com)"
```

You want to match on "computer" name, and use negative look ahead to ignore ones that already have the FQDN portion.

```
$test = Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt
$test -replace "($compname)(?!\.contoso\.com)", $fqdn
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is a regular expression, so you want to match on `$compname` that does not occur before the domain portion of the FQDN. You can achieve this with a [Negative Lookahead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#grouping-constructs):

```
$domain = [regex]::Escape( $fqdn.split( '.', 2 )[1] )
$test -replace "${compname}(?!${domain})", $fqdn
```

Let's break down what this does:

- `$domain = [regex]::Escape( $fqdn.split( '.', 2 )[1] )` - Extract the domain portion of the FQDN, and make sure it's escaped so no special characters are interpreted as regex syntax
- `"${compname}(?!\.${domain})"` - Regex pattern to match on - let's break this down

  - `${compname}` - Insert the `$compname` variable as part of the string
  - `\.` - Match on a literal `.`; the backslash is required as `.` is a special token (matches any character) when processing regular expressions
  - `()` - Grouped expression - let's also break this down

    - `?!` - Negative lookahead operator, tells the grouped expression that this group **cannot** match after the preceeding expression. If matched, this group is discarded from the result.
    - `${domain}` - Same as `${compname}`, just inserting the variable into the expression

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to overwrite the entire line, rather than replace comp name.

```
$match = $test | select-string -pattern "serverName"
$test -replace $match,"serverName = $fqdn" | set-content c:\temp\test.txt
```

This guarantees whatever the entry is will be overwritten by the FQDN.